# How to subtract the sum of two columns from different table and insert the difference to the other column

Tags: c#, sql

I have three tables `STUDENT`, `STUDENTPAYMENTS`, `STUDENTCREDIT`.

In table `STUDENT` there is a column `TotalPayableAmount`, this is the amount needed to be paid by the student.

In table `STUDENTPAYMENTS` there is a column `TotalPaid`, this is the amount paid by the students.

And in `STUDENTCREDIT` there is a column `TotalCredit`, this is where I put/insert the remaining balance of the student.

Please help me to get this result:

```
TotalCredit = TotalPayableAmount - TotalPaid
and Group by IDNumber ..
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view many different tables and then use the columns in a view to subtract them from each other. writing a query and subtracting the columns in a single query will be very hard. 
Create a view with the columns you need and then use the view to subtract the columns that you require.
**How yo create a view**
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp
**Subtracting columns in a view**
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181101/subtraction-of-two-column-in-views